# Percent inhibition from media

Tags: r, statistics

I´m testing a molecule that inhibits bacterial growth (single same concentration for all experiments)

```
a <- 
structure(list(treatment = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), result = c(0.113587347232207, 
0.0126742712294043, 0.000643500643500661, 0.00404682757623936, 
0.821428571428571)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like this:

```
> a
  treatment       result
1         a 0.1135873472
2         a 0.0126742712
3         a 0.0006435006
4         a 0.0040468276
5         a 0.8214285714
```

The table above show 5 experiments where we see bacterial inhibition (1=no_inhibition , 0=max_inhibition)

I take the median:

```
> median(a$result)
[1] 0.01267427
```

I would like to classify my experiments as a percent of deviance from the median and establish scores based on the % inhibition.

For example i want to compute the percent inhibition and rank experiments as a % of inhibition compared to the median.

```
10% inhibition 
20% inhibition
30% inhibition
40% inhibition
50% inhibition
100% inhibition
```

How can i do that ? Does that sounds like a good approach ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? // Row 2 is the median inhibition value, would that be computed as 100% inhibition?

Comment: Questions like "does that sounds like a good approach" aren't a good fit here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. If you want statistical advice, you should seek help at [stats.se] instead.